# Inverse a python Dictionary where values are list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary with keys and where values are in a list.

```
d = {'A':['A1','A2','A3'],'B':['B1','B2']}
```

I want output like this

```
inv_d = {'A1':'A','A2':'A','A3':'A','B1':'B','B2':'B'}
```

I am doing this

```
inv_d  = {v1 for v1 in v:k for k, v in d.items()}
```

Getting error

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-96f1a52e0304>", line 2
    inv_d  = {v1 for v1 in v:k for k, v in d.items()}
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Look up dictionary comprehension syntax again, looks like you made a simple mixup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite your code to the following:

```py
>>> inv_d  = {v1:k for k, v in d.items() for v1 in v}
>>> inv_d
{'A1': 'A', 'A2': 'A', 'A3': 'A', 'B1': 'B', 'B2': 'B'
```

A short explanation. Let's say you just wanted to do this with normal for loops, you would write the following.

```py
inv_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
  for v1 in v:
    inv_d[k] = v1
```

To convert this to a single dict comprehension, you have to keep the same ordering of for loops:

```py
{... for k, v in d.items()  for v1 in v}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a slight edit to your solution, we get:

```
>>> {v1:k for k, v in d.items() for v1 in v}
{'A1': 'A', 'A2': 'A', 'A3': 'A', 'B1': 'B', 'B2': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v}
```

Output:

```
{'A1': 'A', 'A2': 'A', 'A3': 'A', 'B1': 'B', 'B2': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inv_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
  for v1 in v:
    inv_d[k] = v1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over dictionary without using `items` method and it iterates over the key. You could simply write it as follows:

```
inv_d = {value: key for key in d for value in d[key]}
```